# My friend's rope puzzle

Tags: riddle

My friend presented me with this puzzle:
You are presented with a rope, about as long as your arm.
You must hold each end with your forefingers and thumbs, without letting go or adjusting your grip.
The challenge is: can you tie a basic knot? [image: image_of_a_basic_knot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy, if you know how:

> Fold your arms in a knot (so that one of your hands is below the opposite arm and the other hand is over the original arm) before grabbing the rope

Then:

> When you unfold your arms, the knot will be transferred onto the rope

Comment: Wow. This was quicker than I thought.